# How do I modify specific member of array in nested deployment in ARM?

Tags: azure-resource-manager

I have nested deployment which updates `IPConfiguration` to static. Parent deployment is below showing that several `IPconfigurations` are created for single NIC. Later in the same parent template a nested deployment is created to set those IPs from `dynamic` to `static`. This does not work since every execution of that nested deployment is completely overwrites `ipconfigurations` which was set in parent scope. I'm confused how to I modify either individual entries for ipconfigs array or modify all of them at the same in a loop.

*Parent Deployment*

```
{
        "name": "[variables('NICName')]",
        "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
        "apiVersion": "2018-04-01",
        "location": "[variables('VMResourceGroupLocation')]",
        "properties": {
            "copy": [
                {
                    "name": "ipconfigurations",
                    "count": "[parameters('niccount')]",
                    "input": {
                        "name": "[concat('ipconfig',copyIndex('ipconfigurations'))]",
                        "properties": {
                            "subnet": {
                                "id": "[variables('subnetRef')]"
                            },
                            "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
                            "primary": "[equals(copyIndex('ipconfigurations'),0)]"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
```

*Nested Deployment*

```
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
        "apiVersion": "2017-08-01",
        "copy": {
            "name": "deploymentLoop",
            "count": "[parameters('niccount')]"
        },
        "name": "[concat('ipconfig', copyIndex('deploymentloop'))]",
        "dependsOn": [
            "[variables('NICName')]"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "mode": "Incremental",
            "templateLink": {
                "uri": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/artisticcheese/artisticcheesecontainer/master/updateip.json",
                "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
            },
            "parameters": {
                "nicName": {
                    "value": "[variables('nicName')]"
                },
                "ipConfigName": {
                    "value": "[concat('ipconfig', copyIndex('deploymentloop'))]"
                },
                "SubnetRef": {
                    "value": "[variables('SubnetRef')]"
                },
                "privateIp": {
                    "value": "[reference(concat('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/', variables('nicName'))).ipConfigurations[copyIndex('deploymentloop')].properties.privateIPAddress]"
                }
            }
        }
```

Template for nested deployment is below

```
"resources": [
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
        "name": "[parameters('nicName')]",
        "apiVersion": "2018-03-01",
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "properties": {
            "ipConfigurations": [
                {
                    "name": "[parameters('ipconfigName')]",
                    "properties": {
                        "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Static",
                        "privateIPAddress": "[parameters('privateIp')]",
                        "subnet": {
                            "id": "[parameters('subnetRef')]"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
],
```

Comment: not sure I understand the question, you are creating separate deployments, but dont want them to be separate deployment? can we take a step back? whats wrong with what you are doing today? does it achieve what you want it to? if not, what doesnt work? what is the error you are getting?

Comment: I updated question to show my parent deployment. Basically in parent deployment I created 2 Ipconfigs in `copy` loop and then in nested deployment I'm trying to switch those `ipconfigs` from `dynamic` to `static`. It works fine if there is only 1 `ipconfig` but fails if there are multiple since it tries to redeploy each time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to pass to nested deployments all Ips via

```
   "ips": {
    value": "[reference(concat('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/',variables('nicName')))]"                       
    }
```

And then inside nested deployment to have a loop over those

```
            "properties": {
            "copy": [
                {
                    "name": "ipconfigurations",
                    "count": "[parameters('niccount')]",
                    "input": {
                        "name": "[concat('ipconfig',copyIndex('ipconfigurations'))]",
                        "properties": {
                            "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Static",
                            "privateIPAddress": "[parameters('ips').ipConfigurations[copyIndex('ipconfigurations')].properties.privateIPAddress]",
                            "subnet": {
                                "id": "[parameters('subnetRef')]"
                            },
                            "primary": "[equals(copyIndex('ipconfigurations'),0)]"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
```